# FPDF dont want extra generated page

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Hi i am using fpdf and this is my code:

```
<?php
   require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

   $pdf = new FPDF('P','mm',array(45,10));
   $pdf->SetMargins(0,5,0);    
   $pdf->AddPage('L');
   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
   $pdf->Cell(0, 0,'ASERJFBJGFJSFDS');
   $pdf->Output('label','I');
?>
```

This is generating a extra page which i don't want. The first page is empty and the second page is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FPDF's `Cell` method triggers an automatic page break when it detects that the content being added will extend beyond the page break margin (and the value of `AutoPageBreak` is `true`, which is the default).

Just set the page break margin to a small value before adding the cell. I managed to get your code to output only one page by adding:

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 5);
```